# Model and Service in sync angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a probably a basic question, I have been working on angularjs for sometime now, I always struggle to do this "right way".

I have a model in my controller, which is big javascript object which directly works with the UI, it is usually good practice to keep all the Business Logic inside a service to maintain the application. But now how I do I access the model from the controller inside the service, do I pass it as parameter to function's in the service ?(I don't want to do this since its a big model), because I want the model in the controller to get update after executing certain calculation in the service.

(without using broadcast, emit or on)

Comment: No problem with passing the model to the service. Objects are passed by reference, so you won't have memory issue if that is what you are worried about.

Comment: is there any better way or more like angular way of doing this ?.